# React-Router v6 | Getting Template Location

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router v6, and I have these routes (just for this question):

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
      <Route path="items" element={<AllItemsPage />} />
      <Route path="items/:id" element={<ItemPage />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Now, I want to get the template path `items/:id` inside the `<ItemPage />` component.

Currently, when I'm using `useLocation()` hook, I get the pathname, which is `items/2` for example, and I need both - template and pathname.

### Versions

- **React**: `^17.0.2`
- **React Router DOM**: `^6.0.2`

Comment: When you say "template" do you mean the pattern? RRDv6 doesn't appear to expose the route path patterns out to children components. What is the use case here, what are you trying to solve for? Are you trying to build nested links/routes like the `useRoutedMatch` hook was used in v5 with the `path` and `url` properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through React router v6 API docs, AFAIK there is no way provided to get the template directly.

Your best bet would be to pass on props to your components like

```js
<Route path="items/:id" element={<ItemPage pattern="items/:id"/>} />
```

Better, store your templates in an object

```js
const paths = {
  home: "/",
  ...
  items: "items/:id"
}
...
<Route path={paths.items} element={<ItemPage pattern={paths.items}/>} />
```

Comment: In v5 they had `useRouteMatch` which returned the pattern as `path`. Sadly it was removed and is, as this answer correctly states, no longer exposed.